# ArcPy calculating area in att table column in ArcMap - Error 000800: The value is not a member of PYTHON

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, error-000800

Attempting to make the following code work in ArcMap:

```
for i in range(len(l)):

    print("calculating area" + str(i))
    in_layer = l[i]
    exp = "!SHAPE.AREA@ACRES!"
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(in_layer, "Area_Field", exp, "PYTHON 9.3")
    print("next layer" + str(i+1))
```

Getting the following error:

[image]

Trying to follow the first answer in the link here [Calculate area within Python script in ArcMap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57448/calculate-area-within-python-script-in-arcmap), for reference.

Is the expression wrong, or is there a different error in the code?

I am using ArcMap 10.5.1.

Comment: Please always provide error messages as formatted text.

Answer (score 0):

The code below worked:

```
for i in range(len(l)):
    print("calculating area" + str(i))
    in_layer = l[i]
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(in_layer, "Area_Field", "!shape.area@acres!", "PYTHON_9.3")
    print("next layer" + str(i + 1))
```

"Area_Field" was the new field that was created previously and that I was trying to fill out in each layer. Not sure what the error was caused by before.

Following this tutorial also helped: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BKp7O6EWCLA

Comment: Where is `l` set?  If I were to run either this code or the code you presented in your question I would get an error immediately.

Comment: The reason for the original error, which you corrected in this code, was the `'PTYHON 9.3'`.  You had a space in between PYTHON and 9.3, which was incorrect.

Comment: I suggest you do a search and read up on loops in Python.  The code structure being used for looping may work, but it is the least Pythonic way to do it.

Comment: Ah, that is true, I did miss the space. And thank you for the suggestion, I will look into it! Am in the process of going through a Python course, but not advanced enough yet to make the loops more compact. Was planning on rewriting the code after I study some more. Will study up more on loops and cursors.

Comment: I will keep in mind for making the error messages as formatted text for next time.

Comment: I did not include setting the l in this portion, because usually I just put "l=" in the python window, and drag the list of layers that I need